# Rails - Trouble installing capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, qt, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

I have a Rails 5 application that has several forms contained in bootstrap modals. Capybara is having trouble reading the modal content. From reading several other stack overflow articles, it seems I need to install the capybara-webkit gem. However, I am having trouble installing it.

On my initial install, I got an error that said:

```
Command 'qmake ' not available

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0 for inspection.
Results logged to

An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.14.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.14.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Looking around a bit, it seems I need to install QT. So I tried to install using the instructions from this article: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

I am on OS X El Capitan, so I ran:

```
brew install qt@5.5
```

Then I typed this into the command line, per the instructions (I believe. This may be where I messed up):

```
echo 'export PATH="$(brew --prefix qt@5.5)/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

I tried installing the gem again, and got the exact same problem:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: 
/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0
/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170803-82842-1br8b1h.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-gl-dir
--without-gl-dir
--with-gl-include
--without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
--with-gl-lib
--without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
--with-zlib-dir
--without-zlib-dir
--with-zlib-include
--without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
--with-zlib-lib
--without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' not available

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0 for inspection.
Results logged to


An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.14.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.14.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I can't get this working? Help!

Answer (score 0):

With the `echo` example you've just added the export to your .bashrc - You still need to make sure that is loaded into the current PATH environment variable though.  Easiest way to do that is to close the current shell and open a new one, however I've generally found it easier to just go with the

```
brew link --force qt@5.5
```

All this being said, `capybara-webkit` has become pretty outdated in its JS support and requires transpiling and polyfilling for testing most modern apps.  As a beginner to testing JS dependent apps with Capybara you're probably better off using selenium with chrome - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#configuring-and-adding-drivers -
 instead of `capybara-webkit`